# Can this error kill the USB port?

Tags: windows-10

I got this error the other day:

[image]

The mouse and keyboard stopped working..I shut down the computer, tried to turn it on again and it wouldn't turn on...I removed all USB devices,and then computer turns on...attached the keyboard and got the "Power surge on the USB port" again and the keyboard wouldn't turn on...I tried plugging and unplugging several times until it worked....but now one of my USB ports no longer works...I have to plug it into another port...

My question is, can the "Power surge on the USB port" error kill the USB port ?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: How to check if the port is dead ?

Comment: Can't really say for Windows, but my Mac will yell similar at me if I plug an iPad [high power draw] into my 8-port USB hub. It just switches off the power on that port until I unplug it again. It does no other damage.

Comment: @I3gi0n, all you need to do is plug in a USB stick and see if it receives power. If not, you have fried the port.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, can the "Power surge on the USB port" error kill the USB port ?

That USB port is gone, however that message is more likely part of the symptom and not the reason.

Comment: Is there a program you can use to monitor the USB ports in your PC ?